# Example about Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink?

Tags: elixir

Trying to apply [Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html#async_stream_nolink/4) with little test, but not working..

Here is my implementation:

```
defmodule MySupervisor do
    use Supervisor

    def start_link do
        Supervisor.start_link(__MODULE__, [])
    end

    def init([]) do
        children= [
            worker(Basic, [])
        ]

        supervise(children, strategy: :one_for_one)
    end
end

defmodule Basic do
    use GenServer

    def start_link do
        GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [], name: __MODULE__)
    end
end


strings = ["long string", "longer string", "there are many of these"]


stream = Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink(MySupervisor, strings, fn text -> text |> String.codepoints |> Enum.count end)


Enum.reduce(stream, 0, fn {:ok, num}, acc -> num + acc end) |> IO.puts
```

But, I got error:

> ** (EXIT from #PID<0.70.0>) exited in: GenServer.call(MySupervisor, {:start_child, [#PID<0.70.0>, :monitor,
>   {:nonode@nohost, #PID<0.81.0>}, {:erlang, :apply,
>   [#Function<0.118488666 in file:test.exs>, ["long st ring"]]}]},
>   :infinity)
>       ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its
>   application isn't started
>
> 16:24:34.317 [error] GenServer #PID<0.79.0> terminating
>   ** (stop) exited in: GenServer.call(MySupervisor, {:start_child, [#PID<0.70.0>, :monitor, {:nonode@nohost, #PID<0.81.0>}, {:erlang,
>   :apply, [#Function<0.118488666 in file:test.exs>, ["long string"]]}]},
>   :infin ity)
>       ** (EXIT) no process: the process is not alive or there's no process currently associated with the given name, possibly because its
>   application isn't started Last message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.70.0>,
>   {:noproc, {GenServer, :call, [MySupervisor, {:start_child,
>   [#PID<0.70.0>, :monitor, {:nonode@nohost, #PID<0.81.0>}, {:erlang,
>   :apply, [#Function<0.118488666 in file:test.exs
>
> > , ["long string"]]}]}, :infinity]}}} State: {:state, {#PID<0.79.0>, MySupervisor}, :one_for_one, [{:child, #PID<0.80.0>, Basic, {Basic,
> >     :start_link, []}, :permanent, 5000, :worker, [Basic]}], :undefined, 3,
> >     5, [], 0, MySupervisor, []}

Anyone can help? I could not find an example about using [Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html#async_stream_nolink/4)

**EDIT**

Trying to use my own supervisor directly without using it in application, I tried this:

```
{:ok, supervisor} = MySupervisor.start_link
stream = Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink(supervisor, strings, fn text -> text |> String.codepoints |> Enum.count end)
Enum.reduce(stream, 0, fn {:ok, num}, acc -> num + acc end) |> IO.puts
```

But I got error:

> ** (EXIT from #PID<0.70.0>) an exception was raised:
>       ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:EXIT, {:undef, [{Basic, :start_link, [#PID<0.70.0>, :monitor,
>   {:nonode@nohost, #PID<0.81.0>}, {:erlang, :apply,
>   [#Function<0.20003547 in file:t est.exs>, ["long string"]]}], []},
>   {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line:
>   381]}, {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line:
>   406]}, {:gen_server, :try_handle_call,  4, [file: 'gen_server.erl',
>   line: 615]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 5, [file: 'gen_server.erl',
>   line: 647]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl',
>   line: 247]}]}}}
>           (elixir) lib/task/supervisor.ex:265: anonymous fn/4 in Task.Supervisor.build_stream/5
>           (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:332: Task.Supervised.stream_monitor/6
>
> 17:07:53.497 [error] Process #PID<0.81.0> raised an exception
>   ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:EXIT, {:undef, [{Basic, :start_link, [#PID<0.70.0>, :monitor,
>   {:nonode@nohost, #PID<0.81.0>}, {:erlang, :apply,
>   [#Function<0.20003547 in file:test. exs>, ["long string"]]}], []},
>   {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line:
>   381]}, {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line:
>   406]}, {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl',
>   line: 615]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 5, [file: 'gen_server.erl',
>   line: 647]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl',
>   line: 247]}]}}}
>       (elixir) lib/task/supervisor.ex:265: anonymous fn/4 in Task.Supervisor.build_stream/5
>       (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:332: Task.Supervised.stream_monitor/6
>
> 17:07:53.503 [error] GenServer MySupervisor terminating
>   ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:EXIT, {:undef, [{Basic, :start_link, [#PID<0.70.0>, :monitor,
>   {:nonode@nohost, #PID<0.81.0>}, {:erlang, :apply,
>   [#Function<0.20003547 in file:test. exs>, ["long string"]]}], []},
>   {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line:
>   381]}, {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line:
>   406]}, {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl',
>   line: 615]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 5, [file: 'gen_server.erl',
>   line: 647]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl',
>   line: 247]}]}}}
>       (elixir) lib/task/supervisor.ex:265: anonymous fn/4 in Task.Supervisor.build_stream/5
>       (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:332: Task.Supervised.stream_monitor/6 Last message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.70.0>,
>   {{:badmatch, {:error, {:EXIT, {:undef, [{Basic, :start_link,
>   [#PID<0.70.0>, :monitor, {:nonode@nohost, #PID<0.81.0>}, {:erlang,
>   :apply, [#Function<0.20003547 in file:test.ex s>, ["long string"]]}],
>   []}, {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl',
>   line: 381]}, {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl',
>   line: 406]}, {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [f ile:
>   'gen_server.erl', line: 615]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 5, [file:
>   'gen_server.erl', line: 647]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file:
>   'proc_lib.erl', line: 247]}]}}}}, [{Task.Supervisor, :"-build_str
>   eam/5-fun-0-", 4, [file: 'lib/task/supervisor.ex', line: 265]},
>   {Task.Supervised, :stream_monitor, 6, [file: 'lib/task/supervised.ex',
>   line: 332]}]}} State: {:state, {:local, MySupervisor},
>   :simple_one_for_one, [{:child, :undefined, Basic, {Basic, :start_link,
>   []}, :permanent, 5000, :worker, [Basic]}], :undefined, 3, 5, [], 0,
>   MySupervisor, []}
>
> 17:07:53.505 [error] GenServer #PID<0.79.0> terminating
>   ** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: {:error, {:EXIT, {:undef, [{Basic, :start_link, [#PID<0.70.0>, :monitor,
>   {:nonode@nohost, #PID<0.81.0>}, {:erlang, :apply,
>   [#Function<0.20003547 in file:test. exs>, ["long string"]]}], []},
>   {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line:
>   381]}, {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl', line:
>   406]}, {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [file: 'gen_server.erl',
>   line: 615]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 5, [file: 'gen_server.erl',
>   line: 647]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl',
>   line: 247]}]}}}
>       (elixir) lib/task/supervisor.ex:265: anonymous fn/4 in Task.Supervisor.build_stream/5
>       (elixir) lib/task/supervised.ex:332: Task.Supervised.stream_monitor/6 Last message: {:EXIT, #PID<0.70.0>,
>   {{:badmatch, {:error, {:EXIT, {:undef, [{Basic, :start_link,
>   [#PID<0.70.0>, :monitor, {:nonode@nohost, #PID<0.81.0>}, {:erlang,
>   :apply, [#Function<0.20003547 in file:test.ex s>, ["long string"]]}],
>   []}, {:supervisor, :do_start_child_i, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl',
>   line: 381]}, {:supervisor, :handle_call, 3, [file: 'supervisor.erl',
>   line: 406]}, {:gen_server, :try_handle_call, 4, [f ile:
>   'gen_server.erl', line: 615]}, {:gen_server, :handle_msg, 5, [file:
>   'gen_server.erl', line: 647]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file:
>   'proc_lib.erl', line: 247]}]}}}}, [{Task.Supervisor, :"-build_str
>   eam/5-fun-0-", 4, [file: 'lib/task/supervisor.ex', line: 265]},
>   {Task.Supervised, :stream_monitor, 6, [file: 'lib/task/supervised.ex',
>   line: 332]}]}} State: {:state, {#PID<0.79.0>, Supervisor.Default},
>   :simple_one_for_one, [{:child, :undefined, Task.Supervised,
>   {Task.Supervised, :start_link, []}, :temporary, 5000, :worker,
>   [Task.Supervised]}], :undefined, 3 , 5, [], 0, Supervisor.Default,
>   {:ok, {{:simple_one_for_one, 3, 5}, [{Task.Supervised,
>   {Task.Supervised, :start_link, []}, :temporary, 5000, :worker,
>   [Task.Supervised]}]}}}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functions in `Task.Supervisor` are meant to be run only on a Supervisor started with `Task.Supervisor.start_link/1`.

You can either start an unnamed instance and pass the pid to `async_stream_nolink/4`:

```
{:ok, supervisor} = Task.Supervisor.start_link
stream = Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink(supervisor, strings, fn text -> text |> String.codepoints |> Enum.count end)
```

or start a named instance and pass its name:

```
Task.Supervisor.start_link name: MySupervisor
stream = Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink(MySupervisor, strings, fn text -> text |> String.codepoints |> Enum.count end)
```

The output in both cases is `47`.

If you want this supervisor to run alongside your application, you can add it under your application's existing top level supervisor like this:

```
children = [
  supervisor(Task.Supervisor, [name: MySupervisor]),
  ...
]
```

and then do

```
Task.Supervisor.async_stream_nolink(MySupervisor, ...)
```

Comment: ops! I've edited your answer instead of my question!

Comment: I think you may have misread my answer -- even when you pass a pid, you need to pass a pid of a Task Supervisor (`Task.Supervisor.start_link`, not `MySupervisor.start_link`).

Comment: So, how would I customize it? like for example, the strategy or grap the process that has failed..

Comment: There are some options `Task.Supervisor.start_link/1` accepts that are documented here: https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Task.Supervisor.html#start_link/1.

Comment: Hi Dogbert, can you please check this question at elixir forum: https://elixirforum.com/t/handle-info-when-using-task-supervisor-async-stream-nolink/8513